# How to add function to add null value to combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have many class to set ComboBox datasource

```
- Position [DISPLAY, VALUE, ID, NAME]
- Division [DISPLAY, VALUE, ID, NAME]
- SubDivision [DISPLAY, VALUE, ID, NAME, DIVISIONID]
- ect.
```

and i binding data

```
 List<Position> list = new List<Position>;
 list.Add(...);
 cboPosision.DataSource = list;
```

How to create method for ComboBox to insert row Null data

```
 private void SetDataSource(this ComboBox cbo, object dataList, bool IncludeAll)
 {
  if(includeAll) { dataList.Add(null); } //Need Insert object {DISPLAY:"All", VALUE:null}
  cbo.DataSource = dataList;
 }
```

Comment: What happens when you try to add a Position with a Value=null?

Comment: For use in Criteria in form to search data

Comment: I mean, if you create an instance of the Position class with Name="ALL" and Value=null then add this instance to your list. Did you get some problems?

Comment: How can i know what class of dataList, because i use object dataList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:
Create a common interface that all your combobox items must implement:

```
interface IComboBoxItem 
{
    string Display {get;set;}
    object Value {get;set;
}
```

Then use a generic extension method to set that list as a data source:

```
private void SetDataSource<T>(this ComboBox cbo, IList<T> dataList, bool IncludeAll) where T : new, IComboBoxItem 
{
    if(includeAll) 
    { 
        dataList.Add(new T() {Display = "All", Value = null});
    }
    cbo.DisplayMember = "Display";  // This corresponds to the display member of the data object
    cbo.ValueMember = "Value";  // this corresponds to the value member of the data object
    cbo.DataSource = dataList;
}
```

**Note:** code written directly here, there might be some typos.

Comment: You will need to set the display and value members of the combobox.